# Insert Environment Variable using Jinja in SaltStack

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

I am trying to read a JSON file inside a folder. using import_json.
Here is my code

```
{% set instance_id = grains['INSTANCE_ID'] %}
INSTANCE_ID Env Var:
  environ.setenv:
    - name: INSTANCE_ID
    - value: {{ grains['INSTANCE_ID'] }}
    - update_minion: True

{% import_json "/tmp/$INSTANCE_ID/conf.json" as config_properties %}
```

But I am getting this error

```
Data failed to compile:
Rendering SLS 'base:cloud.steps.conf' failed: Jinja error: /tmp/$INSTANCE_ID/conf.json.
```

Although when I insert the INSTANCE_ID manually it works as expected.

What I want is to be able to insert either `$INSTANCE_ID` or directly the grain value `{{ grains['INSTANCE_ID'] }}`

Can someone please help me with this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{% import_json "/tmp/$INSTANCE_ID/conf.json" as config_properties %}
```

I imagine you are trying to evaluate the variable `$INSTANCE_ID` in the above statement. Jinja template evaluates the variables in expression statements.

In this case, the variable is set in the first line, using `set`

```
{% set instance_id = grains['INSTANCE_ID'] %}
```

So, you can use it in expression along with string appends, like

```
{% import_json "/tmp/" ~ instance_id ~ "/conf.json" as config_properties %}
```

The above statement should resolve your error.

Also, I would suggest using a variable to evaluate the value of the string expression above, like

```
{% set conf_json_path = "/tmp/" ~ instance_id ~ "/conf.json" %}
```

and use it like this

```
{% import_json conf_json_path as config_properties %}
```

Hope this help!

---

In case, you wish to use `grains` dictionary directly, you can use the value like so

```
{% set conf_json_path = "/tmp/" ~ grains['INSTANCE_ID'] ~ "/conf.json" %}
```

Comment: thanks. I removed the set line and replaced instance_id with grains['INSTANCE_ID'] and it worked.